# How to handle SQL query where several tables are involved

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the next **table structure**:

**table_one**

```
+-----+------+
| id  | ref  |
+------------+
```

**table_two**

```
+---------+-------+
| id_one  | cont  |  >> Where id_one references id (from first table)
+-----------------+
```

I am trying to do a query like **this**:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM table_one t1
INNER JOIN table_two t2 ON t2.id_one=t1.id
WHERE t2.cont IN (int,int,int,int...)
AND t1.ref=1 LIMIT 0,1
```

...and getting this error *(on phpMyAdmin)*:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check [..] near:
>   'values t1 INNER JOIN values_int t2 ON t2.id_v=t1.id WHERE t2.cont IN
>   (8,13)'

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html) escape it like this:

```
...
FROM `values` t1
INNER JOIN ....
```